# Handling routes and files with express.js and jade

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am having some trouble accessing some image files in my node.js web app when I go to a route that is 1 level deep. This is because the css will look for the asset adding that 1 level of to the beginning of the specified path.

For instance, in my layout I have a link to a css file called main.css. main.css has a class called `.icon{background:url('../imgs/ok.png');}` When I go to my login page `app.get('/login', routes.login)` the path for that file is `/imgs/ok.png`, and here the image loads into the UI. The problem occurs when I try accessing the following route that has one extra level `app.get('/events/:id', routes.loadEvent)`. That extra level gets added to the css url  `/events/imgs/ok.png` and the image no longer loads into the UI.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me figure out a way to fix this.

Thanks in advance

**Here is my app.js file**

```
module.exports = function (Events, db) {
    var express = require('express');
    var validator = require('validator');
    var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
    var passport = require('./auth');
    var routes = require('./routes')(Events);
    var path = require('path'); 
    var app = express();

    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        store: new MongoStore({mongoose_connection: db})
    }))
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./uploads'}));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.set('X-Powered-By', 'TShare');
        next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
    app.use("/event", express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));

    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

    app.get('/events/:id', routes.singleEvent);
    app.get('/login', routes.login);



    return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths in your css - change them so they start `~/` 
The `~` character represents the root of your application.

Comment: I tried doing this:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '~/public')));

 app.use("/event", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '~/public')))`

but it is still not working. app.js and /public are in the same level (at the root of the project)